# Identifying Orders based upon Frontend or Admin Processing

Tags: magento-1.8, database

Is there something in an orders database entry that will tell me if an order was processed by the customer on the frontend of the web site, or if it was processed on the backend by an admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is intentional, but I noticed that the orders placed from the admin have the column `remote_ip` set to `null`.
The orders placed from the frontend have a valid IP address for this field.